# Why am I unable to access SAS Library

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am running the following code in SAS EG:

```
Data sashelp.air;

proc sgplot data=sashelp.air;
    histogram AIR /;
    yaxis grid;
    run;
```

`ERROR: User does not have appropriate authorization level for library SASHELP.`

Comment: Hover over the connector symbol at the rignt upper corner of your E-Guide window and capture the pop-up ([Alt-PrintScreen]). Share that either with your SAS platform administrator or with us.

Answer (score 5):

That error is most likely because of this statement:

```
Data sashelp.air;
```

What that statement does (when it runs) is to tell SAS to overwrite the dataset `sashelp.air` with a new dataset, which has no other statements - so it would overwrite it with an empty dataset with no columns.

Fortunately, you don't have write permission to the `sashelp` library, so that fails.

Remove the line, and only run the `proc sgplot`, and it should work.  If that still gives you an error, then talk to your SAS administrator.

Comment: Yes, that worked. (Y)